# Firefox problem with ubuntu Font when default

Tags: firefox, 14.04, input, html

My Firefox browser is the only browser I know renders site input tags differently, Every other browser (including other Firefox browser renders input tags the same way). See the picture for the difference you can visit the site on https://drupal.org/project/omega_kickstart and I bet it won't look the same way on your firefox installation. I have tried many times to remove the browser and every possible setting but nothing gives.

[image]

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and the newest Firefox (29.0). I have followed these guides for removing it completly on Ubuntu:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825420/how-to-completely-remove-firefox-and-reinstall-in-fedora

http://swiss.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=875495

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1215352

But it does not solve the problem

```
<input>
```

Tag just becomes long at my Firefox browser, What can I do (I don't want to reinstall ubuntu for this, there has to be a simpler way)...

My system fonts are default... But when I change to Waree Bold Oblique it renders normally, how can I restore default font to default?

Comment: A couple sources indicate this is related to fonts: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=461734, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309467

Comment: This is not a browser issue,  this is a website issue. Meaning there `.css` for the `input` tag, is faulty. Width and or other has not been set properly.

Comment: My system fonts are default... But when I change to Waree Bold Oblique it renders normally, how can I restore default font to default?

Comment: css and site rendering is very much browser dependent and personally I find it frustration when developing web pages , they render different in different broswer. Sort of a fact of life, not much you can do about it. Firefox gets it's custom settings from the ~/.firefox directory, so either start with a new profile , `firefox -P` , or delete your .firefox directory `mv ~/.firefox /.firefox.old_data`. You will loose bookmarks, settings, etc. removing  and reinstalling firefox is not going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [@Nattgew](https://askubuntu.com/users/15341/nattgew) for the link, it is a font issue. After downloading

```
wget -O mac-fonts.zip http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac-14.04/macfonts.zip
sudo unzip mac-fonts.zip -d /usr/share/fonts; rm mac-fonts.zip
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

This started happening here is a screenshot after changing fonts.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the answer is to use different fonts, it's thanks to @Nattgew this information was revealed.

Comment: I stand corrected, sorry for the confusion.